# yield with promisified readFile returning undefined

Tags: node.js

I have the following helper method:

```
module.exports.rootUrl = co(function* () {
  const jsonPath = path.resolve(process.cwd(), './server/config.json');

  console.log(jsonPath);
  let config;
  try {
    const readFile = Promise.promisify(fs.readFile);
    const config = yield readFile(jsonPath, 'utf-8');
  } catch (err) {
    console.dir(err);
    yield Promise.reject(err);
  };

  console.dir(config);

  const url = `http://${config.host}:${config.port}/${config.restApiRoot}`;

  console.log(url);

  yield Promise.resolve(url);
})
```

The problem is that the call to `yield. readFile(jsonPath, 'utf-8')` is returning undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're redeclaring `config` (as a block-scoped `const`) inside the `try`, which means that it's out of scope when you `console.dir` it, and you end up logging the (undefined) `config` that you declared with `let`.

This should work:

```
config = yield readFile(jsonPath, 'utf-8');
```